# How to merge conditional formating directives?

Tags: excel

I have a table with two formating conditions. I want to define for the second column a formating rule and the each row. For some cells both conditions match. In this case only one format gets applied to the cell.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uHALjecVfvif5K73Q0dzdJcsUIudqlJPfeqpoMsWfF0/edit?usp=sharing

1. The second column should have either red or green background based on the boolean value.
2. Each row should be crossed out, if the first column of that row contains a number.

As you can see in the example the second formating rule gets applied to column A and C but not to B.

[image]

How to fix this?

The rules are:

- Column B:

  - if `true`, then green background
  - if `false`, then red background
- All cells:

  - if `isnumber(indirect("A" & row()))`, then strike through

Answer (score 0):

The rules you are using would help to explain but it seems all you need is to apply strikethrough format in addition to pink fill for whatever rule is triggering the FALSE formatting.

In other words you can format strikethrough and pink fill at the same time (it's not a choice between one *or* the other).

---

Select ColumnB and apply:

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(A1),B1=FALSE)
```

with pink and strikethrough. Make sure it is above the just pink rule in Rules Manager.

Comment: It is just coincidence, that the false values are in the same row as the numbers. In general no correlation exists between the first an the second column.